# SQL Server: Server-side blob cursor?

Tags: .net, sql-server, binary-data

i'd like to read binary data from a blob, using the Stream interface around it.

But i don't want the blob to have to be loaded entirely client side and stored in memory, or in a file.

i want the code that uses the blob to be able to seek and read, and only as much data that is needed to support seek/read is brought over the wire.

i.e. ***Pretend*** the blob is a 250MB Photoshop image. The thumbnailer code knows how to read the first 8 bytes of an image, recognize it's a PSD file, seek to the offset that will contain the 3k thumbnail, and read that.

So rather than trying to allocate 250MB of memory, or having to create a temporary file, and having to wait for 250MB to be brought over the wire: the hypothetical SQLServerBlobStreamServerCursor class knows how to data traffic to what which is actually asked for.

---

### Research

[HOW TO: Read and Write a File to and from a BLOB Column by Using Chunking in ADO.NET and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317034)
Which talks about being able to read, and write, in chunks. But the code is unreadable being cut off like that i can't stand it. i'll look at it later.

Also [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252517/streaming-directly-to-a-database/252526#252526) mentioned a new SQL Server 2005 [*column*.Write()]3 T-SQL syntax to write data - [could be used to write data in small chunks](http://weblogs.asp.net/alessandro/archive/2008/09/22/conserving-resources-when-writing-blob-values-to-sql-server-and-streaming-blob-values-back-to-the-client.aspx) (to avoid consuming all your server's memory). Maybe there's a [*column*].**Read**() pseudo-method

Microsoft has an article: [Conserving Resources When Writing BLOB Values to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3517w44b(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions of SQL Server you can just use plain SQL with the SUBSTRING() function on binary data types as well as text.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

To get the size of the image:

```
select datalength(blobcolumn) from myimages where imgid = 12345;
```

To read the first 8 bytes:

```
select substring(blobcolumn, 1, 8) from myimages where imgid = 12345;
```

To read 877 bytes, offset 115000 through 115876:

```
select substring(blobcolumn, 115001, 877) from myimages where imgid = 12345;
```

Remember that the substring function is based on a 1-offset, not 0.

If you care about the column potentially changing between reading parts of it, you can put all the different selects within a transaction.

This is untested by me, but older versions of MS SQL Server apparently require the use of the (now deprecated) READTEXT verb and TEXTPTR() function.  Such as:

```
select textptr(blobcolumn) from myimages where imgid = 12345;
```

grab the returned pointer value, say PTR, and use it in the subsequent queries:

```
readtext blobcolumn @PTR 115001 887
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using new Sql Server 2008 FileStream feature for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645940.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use ADO.NET's `SqlDataReader` object with the `SequentialAccess` CommandBehavior. This will allow you to define a buffer size and read the data in chunks.

See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(VS.71).aspx

```
byte[] outbyte;
int bufferSize = 8;
SqlDataReader myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
...
long returnBytes = myReader.GetBytes(1, 0, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
```

Comment: But with sequential access am i not forced to perform sequential access, reading data in chunks? i need to seek around, for example seek to byte offset 237,539,182, and read n bytes starting there. Then seek back y bytes, reading m bytes.

Comment: The "sequential" part of SequentialAccess is that you have to read the columns sequentially because it reads the data one column at a time instead of grabbing the whole row.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to seek around in the data. I believe SQL Server will want to return the entire field.