# file transfer between a client machine and a server machine database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, client-server, file-transfer

I have this SQL database on a server machine in a network and I want any of the client machines to be able to upload and download files to and from the database accordingly where the files will be saved to the server machine file system and their meta data will be stored in the database.
What is the best method to perform that task? and how shall I implement it using C# winform application?
thx in advance @_@

Comment: Do you want them to download files from a physical location on the database server or extract files stored *in* the database itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert and read a pdf file to Sql Server 2005 database using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572525/how-to-insert-and-read-a-pdf-file-to-sql-server-2005-database-using-c)

Comment: Questions like this make me wish that there was a "SEARCH GOOGLE FIRST" auto-response and a "DO A LITTLE RESEARCH YOURSELF" auto-response.

Comment: @Charles: that's not appropriate for this site. If the answer is on SO then you can flag as dupe. But saying "duh that information is freely available on the net" is antithetical to what SO is about man.

Comment: @ Charles Boyung i did search about it dude and i know the main ways but if u have noticed i'm asking about the best ways! not just anyway! besides, everything is available on the net .. the more i search the more i find .. but i have until tomorrow to finish this .. so i needed an expert advice!! isn't that the main idea for SO? :S

Comment: @RandomNoob .. I just explained the same thing in the comments under David's answer :) and i'll rephrase my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @jcollum - I have seen PLENTY of comments telling people the exact same thing. The purpose of the site is NOT to do people's work for them. And there are plenty of times where people plainly say that the asker should just look up the answer online themselves since it is a simple question that a simple search can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the files to be stored in a database?  A file system (which I'm sure the server in question also has) is much more suited to keeping and serving files.

If the files *must* be in the database, then you'd probably just want to store them in a blob field.  Additional fields should be added to the table with data about the files, of course.  File name, file type, maybe file size if you don't want to have to calculate it from the blob on the fly, maybe the user who uploaded it, the time it was uploaded, etc.

At that point you'd interact with it just like any other database record in your application (skipping explanation of that for brevity, there's no shortage of tutorials on the subject), with the additional step of converting to and from byte arrays for the blob data.  Also, [no shortage of examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+store+file+in+sql).

But I have to drive back to my original question.  Why put files in a relational database?

Comment: The database is an archiving system for a company and the clients are the employees of the company. they should be able to upload their reports, files, tasks..etc to the database to prevent data loss, minimize the use of physical files and ease the search for a file method..

Comment: @Majd: Even so, the file system is better suited for the actual files.  Information about the files can easily be stored in a database.  But they can upload files to a file system, data loss can be prevented with redundancy and backup (where do you think the database stores its data... on the disk), etc.  You certainly _can_ store files in a database as binary data, it's just not the _best_ approach by any means.  There's no reason not to have the files on the file system and the relational data in the database.

Comment: ohh .. u got my question in the wrong was and it's clearly my mistake as  RandomNoob in the first comment got confused about this point too .. i'll rephrase the question .. but i explain here first .. the files will be saved to the server machine not in the actual database .. and i'm mainly asking about the best method to move the files from the client machine to the server machine! and store the info of the file in the database afterwards. hope things are clear now

Comment: @Majd: SharePoint is free (given a Windows Server license), has document storage and versioning features, and uses SQL Server as the back end. Why reinvent the wheel when it's free?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if (txtFilePath.Text == pdfFilepath )
    {
        byte [] b=File .ReadAllBytes (pdfFilepath);
        SqlConnection con1=Connection.Conn();
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand ("insert into tbl_Document(Company_Id,FileNo,PdfFile)values(@cid,@fno,@file)",con1);
        cmd .Parameters .AddWithValue("@cid",txtCompanyId.Text);
        cmd .Parameters .AddWithValue("@fno",txtFileNumber.Text);
        cmd .Parameters .AddWithValue("@file",b);
        con1.Open();
        cmd .ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please give a valid file address.");
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
catch
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Process.");
    this.Dispose();
}
```