# Xsd2Code serialize file OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net

I m using **Xsd2Code** to serialize my object in order to generate a Xml file.

It works fine, just when the file contains much data, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`. Here's the code I used to serialize my object :

```
/// Serializes current EntityBase object into an XML document
/// </summary>
// <returns>string XML value</returns>
public virtual string Serialize() {
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
    System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;

    try {
        memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally {
        if (streamReader != null) {
            streamReader.Dispose();
        }

        if (memoryStream != null) {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My request here, is how can I extend the memory buffer, or how can I avoid such an exception?

Regards.

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the `OutOfMemoryException`, including the traceback?  Are you running out of memory inside `Serializer.Serialize()` or inside `streamReader.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: 1) What are you doing with the XML string after you create it? 2) If you run out of memory serializing to a string to output to a file or other stream, why not serialize directly to the stream?

Comment: Sorry for the late, the crash occurs at streamReader.ReadToEnd(), in fact after serializing the the object  i need to get the xml string to save it into database that's why i need to use ReadToEnd()

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the complete `ToString()` output of the `OutOfMemoryException` so it's hard to say for sure how much this will help, but one possibility would be to write directly to a `StringWriter` without creating an intermediate `MemoryStream`, like so:

```
    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        return this.Serialize(Serializer);
    }
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class XmlSerializerExtensions
{
    class NullEncodingStringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding { get { return null; } } 
    }

    public static string Serialize<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer = null, bool indent = true)
    {
        if (serializer == null)
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        // Precisely emulate the output of http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,2c706ead96e5c4fb
        // - Indent by 2 characters
        // - Suppress output of the "encoding" tag.
        using (var textWriter = new NullEncodingStringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter))
            {
                if (indent)
                {
                    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    xmlWriter.Indentation = 2;
                }
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider eliminating the formatting and indentation to save more string memory by setting `indent = false`.

This will reduce your peak memory footprint somewhat, since it completely eliminates the need to have a large `MemoryStream` in memory at the same time as the resulting string.  It won't reduce your peak memory requirement enormously, however, since the memory taken by the `MemoryStream` will have been proportional to the memory taken by the final XML `string`.

Beyond that, I can only suggest trying to [stream directly to your database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252517/streaming-directly-to-a-database).

Comment: @MoezRebai - you might also look to see whether the byte array returned by [`MemoryStream.GetBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be written directly to your database, without needing to be converted to a string.

Comment: @MoezRebai - 1) can you share the full `ToString()` output of the new exception including the traceback?  2) can you share how you are uploading your XML to the database?